# Java Profiler: JProbe Replacement for Mac?

Tags: java, profiler

I have been using JProbe on Windows and I liked it very much. Unfortunately, I have to ditch my Windows PC due to office space limitation so I am left with MACs only. As far as I know, JProbe doesn't have a MAC version so I am looking for an alternative on Mac OS X, preferably free and with Eclipse plugins. Do you have any suggestions?

I already searched other SO posts. I am using JVisualVM (same as NetBeans) but I am looking for something similar to JProbe. I also looked into YourKit and JProfiler. They all look good but they are a little bit pricy for me.

Comment: Can you run a Windows PC inside a VM such as VirtualBox?

Comment: I do have Parallels VM running but you would never do profiling there. The numbers will be skewed due to the VM overhead. I also run Windows natively using bootcamp but it's just a hassle I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never used MAC before :(
I am fan of YourKit :) but since you said you have already looked into it this might be of help. Got it from google!
[Shark- MAC](http://ninjamonkeys.co.za/2008/02/21/java-performance-profiling-on-mac-for-free-using-shark/)

Answer (score 2):

SUN Java SDK now ships with its own profiler, visualVM. On OS X, just type the command `jvisualvm` in a terminal.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [Shark](http://developer.apple.com/tools/sharkoptimize.html).  It's a general profiler, but it handles Java apps as well.

[image: Shark screenshot]